# Remove rows on quartile deviation low or high

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quartile, deviation

Wrote a code

```
df=data.copy()
for column in data.columns:
    Q1= np.quantile(data[column],0.25)
    Q3= np.quantile(data[column],0.75)
    IQR = Q3-Q1
    Low = Q1 - 3*(IQR)
    High = Q3 + 3*(IQR)
    df = df[(df[column] > Low ) | (df[column] < High)][column]
```

How to write the code so that it only accepts what's in the range.
The code is showing an error.

```
----> 9     df = df[(df[column] > Low ) | (df[column] < High)][column]
```

Comment: Which error did it show? Apart from the error, your logic is also wrong. Every row is greater than `Low` or less than `High`.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my logic was wrong. This one worked.

```
df=data.copy()
for column in data.columns:
    Q1= np.quantile(data[column],0.25)
    Q3= np.quantile(data[column],0.75)
    IQR = Q3-Q1
    Low = Q1 - 3*(IQR)
    High = Q3 + 3*(IQR)
    df = df[df[column].between(Low, High)]
```